How to view log information in Azure Web App
I have developed an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app. During development I use loggers at controllers or services like this:
public Result MyService()
{
    _logger.LogInfomation("MyService!");
    // Service's code.
}

However, after deploying to Azure App Service, I cannot find a place to observe these logs. I have tried setting App service logs and looking at Log stream but it doesn't have the information I need.

You need to enable the Application logging and Web Server logging,then check for logs in LogStream.

Hi I already enable it in App Service Logs but the LogStream result was like this not the expected which can be observed in local.

Have you configured Application Insights ?

No not yet. Can you explain more?



Navigate to App Insights Under settings and check is your app is connected to App insights


Navigate to Monitoring and Enable the Application logging and Web server logging


3)Navigate to Log Stream

Hi, Just checked, the App Insights is already connected like this. However the LogStream still remain the same in previous comment.

@NguyenQuocBao - Check the application insights transaction search for the detailed logs.

@NguyenQuocBao Unable to open the image which you have shared

Hi @harshitha, I finally saw it in Application insights. Many thanks.

@NguyenQuocBao - To get the more detailed telemetry/traces configure application insights from the code.

Checkout the documentation from Microsoft about Application Insights, this worked great for me:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics

Refer my SOThread which i have answered.

In the deployed Azure App Service, you can check the logs in Log Stream / Application Insights or even in the KUDU Debug Console.

If you want to check the Information logs in Log Stream, configure  AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics in Program.cs file.

Install the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices  latest NuGet Package.


My Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddLogging(logs =>
{
    logs.AddConsole();    
    logs.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
});

HomeController.cs file:
 public IActionResult Index()
 {
     _logger.LogInformation("MyService!");
     _logger.LogInformation("Logs from Controller");
     return View();
 }


Along with Application Logging enable the below settings.


LogStream:


As already mentioned in comments, enable Application Insights to get the detailed info of the requests/traces.

Refer my SO Thread to configure Application Insights from Code.
